# Implement componentwise and scalar muliplication of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

I've got a container-like template class `foo` and want to implement "componentwise" and "scalar" multiplication:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector

template<typename T>
class foo
{
public:
    foo() = default;
    template<typename U>
    requires std::is_convertible_v<U, T>
    foo(foo<U> const& other) {
        std::copy(other.begin(), other.end(), begin());
    }

    template<typename U>
    requires std::is_convertible_v<U, T>
    foo& operator*=(foo<U> const& rhs)
    {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), rhs.begin(), begin(),
            [](T const& lhs, U const& rhs) { return lhs * rhs;});
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename U>
    requires std::is_convertible_v<U, T>
    foo& operator*=(U const& rhs)
    {
        std::transform(begin(), end(), begin(),
            [&rhs](T const& lhs) { return lhs * rhs; });
        return *this;
    }
    
    template<typename U>
    auto operator*(foo<U> const& rhs) const
    {
        foo<decltype(T{} * U{})> result = *this;
        return result *= rhs;
    }
    template<typename U>
    auto operator*(U const& rhs) const
    {
        foo<decltype(T{} * U{})> result = *this;
        return result *= rhs;
    }

    constexpr auto begin() noexcept { return m_x.begin(); }
    constexpr auto begin() const noexcept { return m_x.begin(); }
    constexpr auto end() noexcept { return m_x.end(); }
    constexpr auto end() const noexcept { return m_x.end(); }

private:
    std::vector<T> m_x;
};

struct bar {
    operator foo<int>() const { return foo<int>{}; }
};

int main()
{
    foo<int> a;
    bar b;

    auto const c = a * b;
}
```

Now, the problem is: If we got `foo<int> a` and `bar b`, how does the compiler know that `a * b` should be the componentwise multiplication and not the scalar multiplication?

The code obviously works when I explicitly cast `b` to `foo<int>`, but is that really necessary?

[Here is the code.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1477b51c34fe2438)

Comment: The operator overload taking `foo<U>` is more constrained than the other one, so where is the perceived conflict? Multiplying two `foo`s is going to call the first overload, and multiplying a `foo<T>` with a `T` is going to use the second.

Comment: Have you actually tested this and gotten an error? If you write `a * b` where `a` and `b` are `foo<int>`, then the first operator overload is a better match because `foo<U>` is more constrained than `U`. And yes, the comment still applies for `foo<int>` and `foo<double>`. I think this question *desperately* needs a [mre] which shows the compiler doing the wrong thing and not meeting your expectations.

Comment: @JanSchultke Here it is: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=1477b51c34fe2438

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing function templates with implicit conversions, and this is a recipe for trouble.
In general, the problem is that implicit conversions are not considered during template argument deduction, so the fact that `bar` is convertible to `foo<int>` doesn't make it select the overload which takes `foo<U> const&`.

#### Add non-template overloads

To fix this, you can add two addition non-template overloads.
Because these member functions aren't templates, implicit conversions like `bar -> foo<int>` work as expected.

These two new overloads don't conflict with the existing function templates because non-templates are better matches in overload resolution.

```cpp
auto operator*(foo const& rhs) const
{
    auto result = *this;
    return result *= rhs;
}

auto operator*(T const& rhs) const
{
    auto result = *this;
    return result *= rhs;
}
```

You can find similar practice in the [constructor of `std::pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair).
There is a constructor for `std::pair` of the same type (copy constructor), but there is also a constructor template that accepts a `std::pair<U1, U2>` of a different type.

#### Constrain your function templates

Furthermore, regardless whether this solves your problem, you should constrain your operator overloads.
You could use the [`std::convertible_to` concept](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/convertible_to) instead of relying on the [`std::is_convertible` type trait](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible):

```cpp
// Alternatively, specify the return type to be
// foo<std::common_type_t<T, U>>; this also acts as a constraint.
// Anything is better than completely unconstrained templates.
template<std::convertible_to<T> U>
auto operator*(foo<U> const& rhs) const
{
    foo<decltype(T{} * U{})> result = *this;
    return result *= rhs;
}

template<std::convertible_to<T> U>
auto operator*(U const& rhs) const
{
    foo<decltype(T{} * U{})> result = *this;
    return result *= rhs;
}
```

*See [working solution at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/jvrPor5eY)*

#### Alternative Solution

You could also define a monolithic `operator*`:

```cpp
template <typename U>
// TODO: constrain
auto operator*(U&& other) {
    // TODO: use if constexpr, traits, and other logic to decide what to do here
}
```

This approach is obviously correct, but would require defining a trait which checks if a type is `foo<X>`, or *foo-like*, etc.

Once again, see the [`std::pair` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair). There is a constructor template taking `P&&`, which is *pair-like*.